# How can I log who download a signed URL in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

To allow streaming directly from `google cloudStorage` (and so preventing me from all complexity and processing costs of proxying downloads), I sent a valid `cloudStorage` link to my end users. As the bucket is private, i signed it with an expire time and save the link for future use.

My challenge now is that I need to control who/when click in the file.

The problem is that I didn't find [trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) which fires when accessing content.

Any tips? Thanks

Comment: Hi @JLCDev, Can you accept TasosV answer? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you will satisfy your needs, using [Cloud Audit logs for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/audit-logs)

In general, [Cloud Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/) maintains three audit logs for each project, folder, and organization:

- Admin Activity
- Data Access
- System Event

Google Cloud Platform services write audit log entries to these logs to help you answer the questions:

- who did what, where, and when within your GCP projects.

Comment: This is a good idea. The problem is that I need the control to work inside the platform, and it seems that StackLog does not fit for this use case, is more like an admin  tool, am I correct?

Comment: Cloud Audit logs is an Admin tool for identifying the use of your Cloud Storage buckets. Thus, your challenge is answered by this one. Can you please elaborate on your hesitation to use Cloud Audit logs? I ran a small test with two test accounts and entering the provided link for the file I was able to see the information on the GCS bucket's logs.

Comment: My end users must see logs not an administrator. Let's say I share a video of a training.  The HR administrator must see who click in that video and who didn't

Comment: I see your point, you would like to externalize these logs to some people (eg Your HR department). In that case, you should enable the Cloud Audit logs and [export them](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/tasks/exporting-logs) in Cloud Storage, or PUB/SUB or BigQuery and then [use those logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs) in order to show them to your staff.